# Ember apps translation

Tags: ember.js

I need to translate my Ember.js application. I've seen [Ember-i18n](https://github.com/jamesarosen/ember-i18n), but I don't really like it approach. Writing something like

```
{{t user.edit.title}}
```

isn't very readable. I'd like better something more similar to the good old [gettext](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/), with `.po` files and so. Maybe something like this:

```
{{_}}Edit user{{/_}}
```

Is there any option I could use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to use a combination of [i18next](http://i18next.com/) and a handlebars helper.

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('__', function(options) {
   var result = i18n.t(options.fn(this));
   return result;
});

{{#__}}Text to translate{{/__}}
```

Not entirely sure if that works, can't test it right now.